# Error with roman numeral chord random chord generator

Tags: python, list, random, append

Hello all this is my first post!

I'm trying to write a simple chord generator using roman numerals. My goal is to just print a random selection up to 8 chords from the list, and add some chord qualities to my list.
This is what I have so far.

```
import time
import sys
import random

def print_slow(str):
  for char in str:
    time.sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Welcome to the Chord Generator.
print_slow("Welcome to the Chord Generator.\n")
print_slow("Randomizing chords\n")
print_slow("....................\n")

chords = ["I","i","II","ii","III","iii","IV","iv","V","v","VI","vi","VII","vii"]
random_chord = random.choice(chords)

for chord in chords[0:7]:
  random_chord += chord + " "

random_chord.append("M" or "m" or "M7" or "m7" or "7" or "m7b5" or "dim")
print(random_chord)
```

My two issues right now are:

1. I run the code over and over and sometimes there wont be any spacing, like so

IVI i II ii III iii IV

2. I get this error trying to append the list:

str' object has no attribute 'append'

I know I'm doing something wrong just not sure what, I want the chord qualities to just random attach themselves to whatever roman numeral it selects. I'd like to add more and inversions as well but for now I'm just trying to get this to work!

Comment: Of course you get an error: `random_chord` is a string, i.e. an element of `chords`. But most importanly: what do you intend to achieve with the line `random_chord.append("M" or "m" or "M7" or "m7" or "7" or "m7b5" or "dim")` ?

Comment: When I hit run I want something like this, iM7 VIm7 V7 vidimin. Im very new to python obviously I don’t know what im doing

Answer (score 0):

Several things to consider here:

1. You are always appending the same first eight chords from the list with a space *after* each one. So if for example the chord `iii` has been selected by the random choice, the result will be `iiiI i II ...`. The only random part is the very first one here.
2. The `("M" or "m" ...)` statement will always evaluate to "M". For selecting a random value, use a list and the random choice function (and of course the `+=` operator) just as above for the chords.

What you probably want is to select a random chord, then to append another random value from the list of chord qualities to this chord and finally to append this plus a space character to the output line (all inside the `for` loop).